# Apply function to rolling window

Tags: matlab, vector

Say I have a long list `A` of values (say of length 1000) for which I want to compute the `std` in pairs of 100, i.e. I want to compute `std(A(1:100))`, `std(A(2:101))`, `std(A(3:102))`, ..., `std(A(901:1000))`.

In Excel/VBA one can easily accomplish this by writing e.g. `=STDEV(A1:A100)` in one cell and then filling down in one go. Now my question is, how could one accomplish this efficiently in Matlab without having to use any expensive for-loops.

*edit*: Is it also possible to do this for a list of time series, e.g. when **A** has dimensions 1000 x 4 (i.e. 4 time series of length 1000)? The output matrix should then have dimensions 901 x 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: For the fastest solution see [Luis Mendo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28079457/1011724)

So firstly using a for loop for this (especially if those are your actual dimensions) really isn't going to be expensive. Unless you're using a very old version of Matlab, the JIT compiler (together with pre-allocation of course) makes for loops inexpensive.

Secondly - have you tried for loops yet? Because you should really try out the naive implementation first before you start optimizing prematurely.

Thirdly - `arrayfun` can make this a one liner but it is basically just a for loop with extra overhead and very likely to be slower than a for loop if speed really is your concern.

Finally some code:

```
n = 1000;
A = rand(n,1);
l = 100;
```

for loop (hardly bulky, likely to be efficient):

```
S = zeros(n-l+1,1);  %//Pre-allocation of memory like this is essential for efficiency!
for t = 1:(n-l+1)
    S(t) = std(A(t:(t+l-1)));
end
```

A vectorized (memory in-efficient!) solution:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:l)
S = std(A(X+Y-1))
```

A probably better vectorized solution (and a one-liner) but still memory in-efficient:

```
S = std(A(bsxfun(@plus, 0:l-1, (1:l)')))
```

Note that with all these methods you can replace `std` with any function so long as it is applies itself to the columns of the matrix (which is the standard in Matlab)

---

**Going 2D:**

To go 2D we need to go 3D

```
n = 1000;
k = 4;
A = rand(n,k);
l = 100;

ind = bsxfun(@plus, permute(o:n:(k-1)*n, [3,1,2]), bsxfun(@plus, 0:l-1, (1:l)'));    %'
S = squeeze(std(A(ind)));
M = squeeze(mean(A(ind)));
%// etc...
```

OR

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:l, 1:l, o:n:(k-1)*n);
ind = X+Y+Z-1;
S = squeeze(std(A(ind)))
M = squeeze(mean(A(ind)))
%// etc...
```

OR

```
ind = bsxfun(@plus, 0:l-1, (1:l)');                                                  %'
for t = 1:k
    S = std(A(ind));
    M = mean(A(ind));
    %// etc...
end
```

OR (taken from [Luis Mendo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28079457/1011724) - note in his answer he shows a faster alternative to this simple loop)

```
S = zeros(n-l+1,k);
M = zeros(n-l+1,k);
for t = 1:(n-l+1)
    S(t,:) = std(A(k:(k+l-1),:));
    M(t,:) = mean(A(k:(k+l-1),:));
    %// etc...
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Is it possible to adjust these answers so that I can apply them to a list of time series, e.g. when **A** has dimensions 1000 x 4 (i.e. 4 time series of length 1000)? The output matrix should then have dimensions **n-l+1 x 4** (using your notation).

Comment: @Tom use a for-loop from `1:4`? Otherwise you can vectorize by going into a third dimension using repmat for example but I really doubt it's worth it

Comment: @Dan Yes, I could easily use a for loop for all of this, but I am trying to compress my code since I have quite a few of such constructions (mean, std, quantile, etc.) and having one/two-liners would help tremendously (and 4 was just an arbitrary number).

Comment: @tom, if your main concern is a clean readable code (which reuse the same functionality many time), put the solution you like here in a subfunction and just call that in your main code.

Comment: @Dan, there is a typo in your for loop: `for k = 1:(n-1+1)` should be `for k = 1:(n-l+1)`

Comment: @Tom There is no need for a loop over the second dimension (`1:4`); `std` already handles this, as it works along each column of a matrix input. You can see a possible realization of this in my answer (as well as a significant speedup over the loop approach)

Answer (score 7):

What you're doing is basically a filter operation.

If you have access to the image processing toolbox,

```
stdfilt(A,ones(101,1)) %# assumes that data series are in columns
```

will do the trick (no matter the dimensionality of `A`). Note that if you also have access to the parallel computing toolbox, you can let filter operations like these run on a GPU, although your problem might be too small to generate noticeable speedups.

Comment: Good point, you need to supply the mask, not the filter size.

Answer (score 7):

To minimize number of operations, you can exploit the fact that the standard deviation can be computed as a difference **involving second and first moments**,

[image] 
and moments over a rolling window are obtained efficiently with a **cumulative sum** (using [`cumsum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html)):

```
A = randn(1000,4); %// random data
N = 100; %// window size
c = size(A,2);
A1 = [zeros(1,c); cumsum(A)];
A2 = [zeros(1,c); cumsum(A.^2)];
S = sqrt( (A2(1+N:end,:)-A2(1:end-N,:) ...
    - (A1(1+N:end,:)-A1(1:end-N,:)).^2/N) / (N-1) ); %// result
```

### Benchmarking

Here's a comparison against a loop based solution, using [`timeit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html). The loop approach is as in [Dan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28062734/2586922) but adapted to the 2D case, exploting the fact that [`std`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html) works along each column in a vectorized manner.

```
%// File loop_approach.m
function S = loop_approach(A,N);
[n, p] = size(A);
S = zeros(n-N+1,p);
for k = 1:(n-N+1)
    S(k,:) = std(A(k:(k+N-1),:));
end

%// File bsxfun_approach.m
function S = bsxfun_approach(A,N);
[n, p] = size(A);
ind = bsxfun(@plus, permute(0:n:(p-1)*n, [3,1,2]), bsxfun(@plus, 0:n-N, (1:N).')); %'
S = squeeze(std(A(ind)));

%// File cumsum_approach.m
function S = cumsum_approach(A,N);
c = size(A,2);
A1 = [zeros(1,c); cumsum(A)];
A2 = [zeros(1,c); cumsum(A.^2)];
S = sqrt( (A2(1+N:end,:)-A2(1:end-N,:) ...
    - (A1(1+N:end,:)-A1(1:end-N,:)).^2/N) / (N-1) );

%// Benchmarking code
clear all
A = randn(1000,4); %// Or A = randn(1000,1);
N = 100;
t_loop   = timeit(@() loop_approach(A,N));
t_bsxfun = timeit(@() bsxfun_approach(A,N));
t_cumsum = timeit(@() cumsum_approach(A,N));
disp(' ')
disp(['loop approach:   ' num2str(t_loop)])
disp(['bsxfun approach: ' num2str(t_bsxfun)])
disp(['cumsum approach: ' num2str(t_cumsum)])
disp(' ')
disp(['bsxfun/loop gain factor: ' num2str(t_loop/t_bsxfun)])
disp(['cumsum/loop gain factor: ' num2str(t_loop/t_cumsum)])
```

**Results**

I'm using Matlab R2014b, Windows 7 64 bits, dual core processor, 4 GB RAM:

- 4-column case:

  ```
  loop approach:   0.092035
  bsxfun approach: 0.023535
  cumsum approach: 0.0002338

  bsxfun/loop gain factor: 3.9106
  cumsum/loop gain factor: 393.6526
  ```
- Single-column case:

  ```
  loop approach:   0.085618
  bsxfun approach: 0.0040495
  cumsum approach: 8.3642e-05

  bsxfun/loop gain factor: 21.1431
  cumsum/loop gain factor: 1023.6236
  ```

So the `cumsum`-based approach seems to be the fastest: about **400 times faster** than the loop in the 4-column case, and **1000 times faster** in the single-column case.

Comment: Good point about just using `,:` in the for loop to work on the 2D case. Can you add the bsxfun solutions etc to your benchmarking?

Comment: Nice one. It pays to go back to the basic definition sometimes. (_and thanks for the `timeit` link!_)

Comment: @Dan Sure! I'll have to do it in the evening, as I don't have the same Matlab version now

Comment: Love these hacks! These function calls eat up lot of runtime in them!

Comment: @Dan Updated. `bsxfun` sits between `for` and `cumsum`. I had to modify the `bsxfun` line to `bsxfun(@plus, permute(0:n:(p-1)*n, [3,1,2]), bsxfun(@plus, 0:n-N, (1:N).'));`. The changed part is `0:n-N`, and also some `o` should be `0` (the other changes are just to adapt to my variable names). Please check and maybe update your answer

Answer (score 5):

Several functions can do the job efficiently in Matlab.

On one side, you can use functions such as `colfilt` or `nlfilter`, which performs computations on sliding blocks. `colfilt` is way more efficient than `nlfilter`, but can be used only if the order of the elements inside a block does not matter. Here is how to use it on your data:

```
S = colfilt(A, [100,1], 'sliding', @std);
```

or

```
S = nlfilter(A, [100,1], @std);
```

On your example, you can clearly see the difference of performance. But there is a trick : both functions pad the input array so that the output vector has the same size as the input array. To get only the relevant part of the output vector, you need to skip the first `floor((100-1)/2) = 49` first elements, and take `1000-100+1` values.

```
S(50:end-50)
```

But there is also another solution, close to `colfilt`, more efficient. `colfilt` calls `col2im` to reshape the input vector into a matrix on which it applies the given function on each distinct column. This transforms your input vector of size [1000,1] into a matrix of size [100,901]. But `colfilt` pads the input array with 0 or 1, and you don't need it. So you can run `colfilt` without the padding step, then apply `std` on each column and this is easy because `std` applied on a matrix returns a row vector of the stds of the columns. Finally, transpose it to get a column vector if you want. In brief and in one line:

```
S = std(im2col(X,[100 1],'sliding')).';
```

Remark: if you want to apply a more complex function, see the code of `colfilt`, line 144 and 147 (for v2013b).

Comment: I like this answer very much...

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is speed of the `for` loop, you can greatly reduce the number of loop iteration by folding your vector into an array (using `reshape`) with the columns having the number of element you want to apply your function on.

This will let Matlab and the JIT perform the optimization (and in most case they do that way better than us) by calculating your function on each column of your array.

You then reshape an offseted version of your array and do the same. You will still need a loop but the number of iteration will only be `l` (so `100` in your example case), instead of `n-l+1=901` in a classic `for` loop (one window at a time).
When you're done, you reshape the array of result in a vector, then you still need to calculate manually the last window, but overall it is still much faster.

Taking the same input notation than Dan:

```
n = 1000;
A = rand(n,1);
l = 100;
```

It will take this shape:

```
width = (n/l)-1 ;           %// width of each line in the temporary result array
tmp = zeros( l , width ) ;  %// preallocation never hurts
for k = 1:l                 
    tmp(k,:) = std( reshape( A(k:end-l+k-1) , l , [] ) ) ; %// calculate your stat on the array (reshaped vector)
end
S2 = [tmp(:) ; std( A(end-l+1:end) ) ] ;  %// "unfold" your results then add the last window calculation
```

If I `tic ... toc` the complete loop version and the folded one, I obtain this averaged results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.057190 seconds. %// windows by window FOR loop
Elapsed time is 0.016345 seconds. %// "Folded" FOR loop
```

*<sub>I know `tic/toc` is not the way to go for perfect timing but I don't have the `timeit` function on my matlab version. Besides, the difference is significant enough to show that there is an improvement (albeit not precisely quantifiable by this method). I removed the first run of course and I checked that the results are consistent with different matrix sizes.</sub>*

---

Now regarding your "one liner" request, I suggest your wrap this code into a function like so:

```
function out = foldfunction( func , vec , nPts )

n = length( vec ) ;
width = (n/nPts)-1 ;
tmp = zeros( nPts , width ) ;

for k = 1:nPts
    tmp(k,:) = func( reshape( vec(k:end-nPts+k-1) , nPts , [] ) ) ;
end
out = [tmp(:) ; func( vec(end-nPts+1:end) ) ] ;
```

Which in your main code allows you to call it in one line:

```
S = foldfunction( @std , A , l ) ;
```

The other great benefit of this format, is that you can use the very same sub function for other statistical function. For example, if you want the "mean" of your windows, you call the same just changing the `func` argument:

```
S = foldfunction( @mean , A , l ) ;
```

Only restriction, as it is it only works for vector as input, but with a bit of rework it could be made to take arrays as input too.

Comment: You can download `timeit` from [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function). Also, see my answer: a significant improvement can be made over the loop based approach