# How to find standard deviation of sub-image 3x3 in a image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a image I, and I want to compute the standard deviation of all sub-image 3 by 3 that are extracted from the image I. Based on the definition of standard deviation, firstly, I will compute the mean value of sub-images, and then compute the mean square between image I and that mean to get standard deviation. This is my image I and my code to compute it. But it does not returns true answer. Could you see help me

[image]

The arrow indicates the moving of window. This is my code

```
%% Compute the mean value
mask = fspecial('average', 3);
mean_sub= imfilter(A, mask, 'replicate');
%% How to compute the standard deviation for each sub-image
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the answers to this question: [Apply function to rolling window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062363/apply-function-to-rolling-window/28062734#28062734)

But also try (From [Jonas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28062684/1011724)):

```
stdfilt(A,ones(3))
```

I imagine that's a rolling window with overlaps though and it's not clear if you want a rolling window with or without overlaps?

Comment: Yes. My window is moved with 1 pixel that means it will overlap window. Let see my matlab code to see more detail. For overlap window, which is good method